# Creating a Gradle Grails project in Intellij

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-13

I have created a Grails and Gradle project in Intellij (following the instructions here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-gradle-project-with-grails-integration.html).

However, after I generate the Grails project (using the init gradle task), the Grails View does not appear as in step 5 in those instructions.

I can't find any way to make Intellij recognise it as a Grails project. When I do 'Add Framework Support' there is no grails option. When I right click on the project there is no 'Grails' option. So I can't run Grails commands or do actions such as create a new controller.

I am using Intellij 13.1.3, Grails 2.5.0, Gradle 2.8 and Grails Gradle Plugin 2.2.0.RC1. I have tried a number of different versions of each of these with no success.

Does anyone have this working or know how to get Intellij to recognise a Grails project with Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Typical - after several days trying I found the answer 5 minutes after posting... This was not supported in Intellij 13. I have now tried in Intellij 14.1.5 and the Grails View appears straight away! So the answer is to upgrade Intellij to v14.

Links:

- https://github.com/grails/grails-gradle-plugin/issues/66
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-120860
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116815